# Remove zero values from a Java HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a `HashMap` with float values.

```
HashMap<Integer,Float> map : {(1,0.0),(2,0.0),(3,2000.0),(4,3000.0)}
```

I want to remove all the entries in it with zero values.
The result should be:

```
 map : {(3,2000.0),(4,3000.0)}
```

**Update: I'm using Java 7**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of Java 8 you can simply use

```
map.values().removeIf(f -> f == 0f);
```

According to the [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf(java.util.function.Predicate)) this will remove all of the elements of `map` that satisfy the given predicate.

EDIT
As you updated your question, that you are using Java 7 use an `Iterator` on the `values()`:

```
Iterator<Float> iterator = map.values().iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    if (iterator.next() == 0f) {
        iterator.remove();
    }
}
```

This works because according to the [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#values()) `map.values()`

> Returns a `Collection` view of the values contained in this map. The
>   collection is backed by the map, so changes to the map are reflected
>   in the collection, and vice-versa.

Comment: Ya correct! But I'm using Java 7 in my Android studio. I have updated my question.

Comment: @SandeepYohans I've extended my answer.

Comment: This code looks simpler than mine! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
for (Iterator<Map.Entry<Integer,Float>> it = map.entrySet().iterator(); 
 it.hasNext();) 
 {
     Map.Entry<Integer, Float> entry = it.next();
     if (entry.getValue() == 0.0) {
        it.remove();
     }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention on compare not integer values. `double` and `float` should not be compared with `==`. This should be a **rule**, because this is precise vlue, and `== 0` should menas smth. like `-10E-12 <= float <= 10E-12` (delta range).

```
// Java 7
Iterator<Float> it = map.values().iterator();

while (it.hasNext()) {
    if (it.next().compareTo(0f) == 0)
        it.remove();
}

// Java 8
map.values().removeIf(value -> Float.compare(value, 0) == 0);
```

Comment: Or : `it.next().compareTo(0f)`

Comment: No point calling Float.compare (or compareTo) as that simply implies `==`. It certainly doesn't use deltas.